# Octave 3D mesh, data from file

Tags: matlab, octave, mesh, 3d

I have a big file with 3 columns: density, dimension, value.
example:

```
10 0.3 200  
10 0.4 300  
20 0.3 250  
20 0.4 320  
...
```

I am trying to draw a 3d plot - mesh with `mesh()` function in octave, like this:

```
data = load ("file.txt");  
mesh(data(:,1), data (:,2), data (:,3));
```

Problem I have is , I always get error:

`rows (z) must be the same as length (y), columns (z) must be the same as length (x).`

It worked with function `plot3()`, but I would like a mesh kind of plot.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! While Octave and MATLAB-related questions are on topic here, they are expected to have a scientific focus. This question can be answered by simply reading the MATLAB [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html) for the `mesh` function. Note that if `X` is of size $n\times 1$ and `Y` is of size $m\times 1$, then `Z` is expected to be of size $n\times m$ in `mesh(X,Y,Z)`.

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry for that, but purpose is purely scientific-al. I knew about the dimensions, just didn't know how to apply my data to that function. reshape() function is the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mesh` function plots functions `z=f(x,y)`. So to call the `mesh()` function, you must have 2D data. You can give vectors for `x` and `y`, but `z` must be an array with `length(x)` rows and `length(y)` columns, or `x` and `y` and `z` must be all be 2D arrays of the same size. Your data has been pulled out into a single, long vector which you need to two-dimensionalize.

I believe the `reshape` function will do what you need. E.g. something like:

```
x=reshape(data(:,1),m,n);
y=reshape(data(:,2),m,n);
z=reshape(data(:,3),m,n);
mesh(x,y,z);
```

where `m` and `n` are the appropriate dimensions in `x` and `y` of your data.

Comment: Thanks for explaining and reshape function! I manually entered x,y vectors since I know the interval: start, end and step and reshaped z-data and it works now.

Comment: There's also a `vec2mat` function in MATLAB, but I didn't find its counterpart in Octave. `reshape` goes back a long way, but `vec2mat` may be new.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be:

Call your 3 data vectors aa,bb,cc and assume that aa and bb represent a point on the plane and cc is the height above that plane.

Create a grid:

```
x_plot = linspace(min(aa),max(aa),100);
y_plot = linspace(min(bb),max(bb),100);
[XI,YI] = meshgrid(x_plot,y_plot);
```

Create the interpolant:

```
ZI = griddata(aa,bb,cc,XI,YI);
```

And plot

```
figure()
mesh(XI,YI,ZI)
```